# How to handle data changes in Flux/React?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, reactjs, reactjs-flux

So far I worked quite thoroughly through the two official Flux architecture examples (https://github.com/facebook/flux).

However, I am really unsure of how you would accomplish a change of data after the initial data has been rendered.

For instance, imagine a todo item changes in the example because of a server response, how would that be implemented to have the according item updating correctly without using setProps() in the item component (which is, as far as I understood, prohibited)?

This might be more of React-related misunderstanding - looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea with flux is that you set your React component's internal state (or part of it) to an object or value from a store every time that store changes.

So for example something like this (not real code, but to give you an idea):

```
var Component = react.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { 
            items: Flux.getStore("ItemStore").getItems()
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.store = Flux.getStore("ItemStore");
        this.store.addChangeListener(this.onStoreChange)
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.store.removeChangeListener(this.onStoreChange);
    },

    onStoreChange: function() {
        this.setState({
            items: this.store.getItems()
        });
    },

    render: function() {

        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items; i++) {
            items.push(
                <li key={i}>{this.state.items[i]}</li>
            );
        }

        return (
            <ul>{items}</ul>
        );
    }
});
```

What this example component does is render a list of `this.state.items` that reside in a store called `ItemStore` and are accessed by `ItemStore.getItems()`.  So take a look at the `componentDidMount` which gets the store, binds a callback to whenever the store is changed `onStoreChange` and then sets the current component state of `items` to the items array provided by `store.getItems()`.

As a result when the component is first mounted it gets the current items from the store and displays them, whenever the store changes it will execute `onStoreChange` which gets the items again from the store and sets them again via `this.setState()`.

Naturally we want to be clean so this component also removes the `onStoreChange` binding when the component is being unmounted.

Note: Remember that calling `this.setState()` inside `componentDidMount` does *not* cause a component re-render :)

More on this in the facebook-flux documentation here: http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#listening-to-changes-with-a-controller-view

Comment: Great explanation, but one nit: I believe the use of both setState() inside componentWillMount and getInitialState() is redundant.  getInitialState() can simply call store.getItems().  The only thing that needs to happen in componentWillMount is the call to addChangeListener().

Comment: componentWillMount should be componentDidMount, or else you'll leak event emitters in node.

Comment: Good point, I've not used react in anything outside of the browser currently.

Comment: @MikeDriver where is `componentWillMount `? Did you make a typo or miss something?